# How to Consume data from Azure DocumentDB using API in R

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to consume documentdb JSON data in R dataframes. I tried using the simple API consumption.

```
library("JSON")
web_page=getURL("documentdb URI", userpwd = "abc:psswrd")
```

I also followed the link "[DocumentDB web API access with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097140/documentdb-web-api-access-with-r)" But not able to figure out how to connect.

Comment: Updated with sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query DocumentDB resources using the REST API, first, you need to generate the Azure documentDB auth header for REST API calls. For more details, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources#a-nameconstructkeytokena-constructing-the-hashed-token-signature-for-a-master-token) and my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147894/azure-documentdb-auth-header-in-r). Second, you can interact with DocumentDB by making an HTTP request with the package [`httr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf).

For more information on how to use REST to query DocumentDB resources, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api.

Here is a sample code to list all databases by using REST from R client:

```
library(digest)
library(base64enc)
library(httr)

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")

endpoint = "https://{your-database-account}.documents.azure.com";
masterKey = "aTPETGJNV3u7ht9Ip2mo...";    # replace with your master key                   

currentDate <- tolower(format(Sys.time(), "%a, %d %b %Y %T", tz = "GMT", usetz = TRUE))

generateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature <- function(verb, resourceId, resourceType) {

  key <- base64decode(masterKey)
  text <- sprintf("%s\n", paste(tolower(verb), tolower(resourceType), resourceId, currentDate, "", sep="\n"))
  body <- enc2utf8(text)
  signature <- base64encode(hmac(key, body, algo = "sha256", raw = T))
  token <- sprintf("type=master&ver=1.0&sig=%s", signature)

  return(URLencode(token, reserved = TRUE))

}


# LIST all databases

verb <- "GET"
resourceType <- "dbs"
resourceLink <- "dbs"
resourceId = ""

authHeader = generateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType)

headers <- c("x-ms-documentdb-isquery" = "True",
            "x-ms-date" = currentDate,
            "x-ms-version" = "2015-08-06",
            "authorization" = authHeader)

r <- GET(paste(endpoint, resourceLink, sep = "/"), add_headers(headers))
print(content(r, "text"))
```

EXECUTE a query

```
# EXECUTE a query

databaseId <- "FamilyDB"        # replace with your database ID      
collectionId <- "FamilyColl"    # replace with your collection ID
verb <- "POST"
resourceType <- "docs"
resourceLink <- sprintf("dbs/%s/colls/%s/docs", databaseId, collectionId)
resourceId = sprintf("dbs/%s/colls/%s", databaseId, collectionId)

authHeader = generateMasterKeyAuthorizationSignature(verb, resourceId, resourceType)

headers <- c("x-ms-documentdb-isquery" = "True",
            "x-ms-date" = currentDate,
            "x-ms-version" = "2015-08-06",
            "authorization" = authHeader,
            "Content-Type" = "application/query+json")

body = list("query" = "SELECT * FROM c")            

r <- POST(paste(endpoint, resourceLink, sep = "/"), add_headers(headers), body = body, encode = "json")
print(content(r, "text"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i followed your earlier blog, i am now able to get the generated key "f2jgWXb2BAQUK4eVk8RSNwDu7eT/Yeq+uNFgmR4fRoNY=" , After that not able to get how to use this key. - @Aaron Chen - MSFT

Comment: OK, I looked into this and I will share details later today.

Comment: Thank you so very much - @Aaron Chen - MSFT, It worked out. :)

Comment: My pleasure. You can mark it as answer which may help other communities who may face the same issue.